# Kubernetes can not find the server via clean installation

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I have been trying to learn Kubernetes with Docker to run containers and manage them with Kubernetes.

I use this web-page for installations: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-kubectl/

I have my own Debian/Linux server machine that I want to build and configure Kubernetes.

After following the `kubectl` installation steps, I get an error like:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"16", GitVersion:"v1.16.3", GitCommit:"b3cbbae08ec52a7fc73d334838e18d17e8512749", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2019-11-13T11:23:11Z", GoVersion:"go1.12.12", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

**kubectl version --short:**

```
Client Version: v1.16.3
Error from server (NotFound): the server could not find the requested resource
```

**microk8s.kubectl version --short:**

```
Client Version: v1.16.3
Server Version: v1.16.3
```

I have tried the local `microk8s` and used as `microk8s.kubectl` and with that installation, I was able to configure and even make the container work. However, the regular `kubectl` can not find the server. These two have different installations and different names, folders etc. I assume that one will not break or have any impact on the other one.

Edit: Based on the suggestion of Suresh, I did `kubectl config view` and the result is:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters: []
contexts: []
current-context: ""
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users: []
```

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: `kubectl config view` will list out all the clusters and context in your kubeconfig file, then `kubectl config use-context` to select the correct cluster

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I updated my answer with the result of the command. It seems like config is empty.

Comment: so it seems,  you do not have link to kubeconfig file

Comment: can you check if the file exists `$HOME/.kube/config`

Comment: I have access to config file, which is the same result of the above command. It is just empty.

Comment: `microk8s.kubectl get nodes` can you run it ? I never used microk8s myself, but the docs say https://microk8s.io/docs/

Comment: Yeah, I have my Linux server name as a node correctly with version 1.16.3

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203228/discussion-between-suresh-vishnoi-and-sojimanatsu).

Answer (score 1):

`microk8s.kubectl config view --raw > $HOME/.kube/config`

If you already have kubectl installed and you want to use it to access the microk8s deployment you can export the cluster's config with [accessing-kubernetes on microk8s](https://github.com/ubuntu/microk8s/blob/eb1183bba6da68982ce816a5ea4656591f9ecdfa/README.md#accessing-kubernetes)

Microk8s put the kubeconfig file at different location.

> To avoid colliding with a kubectl already installed and to avoid overwriting any existing Kubernetes configuration file, microk8s adds a microk8s.kubectl command, configured to exclusively access the new microk8s install. When following instructions online, make sure to prefix kubectl with microk8s.

```
microk8s.kubectl get nodes
microk8s.kubectl get services
```

Comment: I already used, and succeeded with microk8s. But it is a local development environment. I want to use the default kubectl command to create server and access it

Comment: `kubectl` is just a k8s client to access the api-server and CRUD operation on its resources.  what you want to create ?

Comment: I figured it out by adding gcloud server to the kubectl config at the end. I wanted to have accessible kubernetes environment from outside. Some people declared that wtih microk8s you cant do it because it is meant to be tested and executed in local environment.